# scanf and printf for loop different amount of output

Tags: c, debugging, for-loop, printf, scanf

THe error I get is that the scan will take one more digit than the print loop.
I have example code after the loops. Would anyone know why that is?

```
   int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

        //Throw error is *Argv[] is not an integer
        //assuming it was an integer
        int cnt = (int)(argv[1][0] - '0');
        printf( "number is %d\n", cnt );
        //
        printf("Enter %i integer values to place in tree:\n", cnt);
        for ( i1 = 0; i1 < cnt; ++i1) {
                scanf( "%d\n", &elemArray[i1] );
        }

        //first ouput "INput Values"

         for ( i2 = 0; i2 < cnt; ++i2) {
               printf( "%d\n", elemArray[i2] );
        }

        //Build tree with each element
        return 0;
}
```

Ouput is:

```
Enter 5 integer values to place in tree:
1
2
3
4
5
6
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: How many times did it prompt you for a number?

Comment: 6 times @Martin James. It tried something with the address of &elemArray and that wasn't it.

Comment: I figured it out. It was 'scanf( "%d\n", &elemArray[i1] );' to be changed to `scanf( "%d", &elemArray[i1] );`

Comment: What do you have against `cnt = atoi (argv[1])`? Include the `stdlib.h` header.

Comment: Yes, good question it was once a dark friend. But I can consider it an ally now.

Comment: He has a brother named `strtol` that works too it `atoi` still has those dark tendencies...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was 
`scanf( "%d\n", &elemArray[i1] );` to be changed to 
`scanf( "%d", &elemArray[i1] );`

Comment: Awesome. I would then remove my answer.